# How can I ensure I'm using JDK version 1.6?

Tags: java, sun-java6-jdk

Before I installed Java JDK1.6 on WinXP machine I typed from the CMD line

```
c:\javac
'javac' is not recognized as internal command ...
```

Here I concluded I did not have a JDK installation on my PC

So, I installed java 1.6.0_30

```
c:\javac
Usage: javac <options> <source> files . ....
```

Conclusion: I now have JDK 1.6 installed

```
c:\java -version 
java version "1.4.2_06"
```

Conclusion: I don't have JDK 1.6

Discovery:
I have the following files on my hard disk as follows:

```
c:\DevSuiteHome\jre\1.4.2.\bin\java.exe    -- before I installed JDK 1.6
c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_30\java.exe -- recently installed.
```

My PATH Environment points to both JDKs

```
 c:\path 
 c:\DevSuiteHome_1\jck\jre\bin;c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_30\jre\bin...
```

Questions:
How can I get 'java -version' to reference 1.6.0_30?
Can I expect errors with my java code because I have two JDK versions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't point to the one you want. Amend your PATH. Remove both these references.

```
c:\DevSuiteHome_1\jck\jre\bin;c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_30\jre\bin
```

Add this.

```
c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_30
```

Now open a cmd prompt, then run java -version and hopefully is 1.6

And no you won't get errors having 2 java versions. It'd only use one or the other.